# App Android Limit

Tags: android

I'm trying to attach a zip file to my project that contains app resorces. The size of this file is undetermined but may be large.

There will be some problem of disk limitation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by attach?
If you mean this will be part of the installation file (final APK published at the market) there is a size limit of 50mb for most devices and 30mb for some other Samsung devices.
If you mean downloading it later to the SD card, there is no size limit other than the free space of the SD card.

Comment: What happen if the zip file is downloaded from internet and the device doesn't have sd card?

Comment: If the device doesn't have any internal memory / sd card you won't be able to save the file. But imagining an Android device without any of these is hard...

Answer (score 0):

Large projects could encounter problems on the market as well. There is a limit for them there. If you do not plan on using in the market then there is less of a worry, unless this zip file is huge(Larger than SD card space).

Other restrictions are mentioned in this post.

[Old Size limit post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246941/what-is-the-normal-procedure-to-submit-an-app-to-the-google-marketplace/7247034#7247034)